# Using Typescript & Knockout, how do I nest Models?

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, knockout-mapping-plugin

I want to use Models to describe my data. I do this by defining a Model with properties of type `KnockoutObservable<T>`. I then map the data to an instance of this Model class. This works all well and good in a simple case like this:

```
class PersonModel extends Model {
    public Name: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable<string>("");
    public Age: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable<number>(0);
}
```

But say I want to nest a model inside a model like so:

```
class PersonModel extends Model {
    public Name: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable<string>("");
    public Age: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable<number>(0);
    public Children: KnockoutObservableArray<PersonModel> = ko.observableArray<PersonModel>([]);
}
```

In my mapping function, how do I know that `Children` is a `PersonModel` so I can create an instance of it for each entry? I could just create a generic object, but then I'd lose all the functionality of `Model`. Is this possible? I know how to do it in C#, I could just use Activator and create a new instance of the generic type, but this is, to my knowledge, impossible in TypeScript. I'm racking my brain on this and would appreciate any insight into some possible solutions.

Comment: Do you get a build error, what error?

Comment: the problem is that I have no way of knowing that I need to create an instance of `PersonModel` for each object in the Children array.

Comment: But you just told me, so you know. Are you having a problem with the mapper? What do you have so far?

Comment: Note: A tree is not the correct structure for the inheritance of real people. Real people have 2 parents and can marry [distant] cousins. (My 100th grand father is also one of your grand fathers).

Comment: the problem is I'm trying to automate this with a generic mapping function. I can tell the mapping function that the json response is a `PersonModel`, but how will the mapping function know that the Children property is an array of `PersonModel`s

Comment: OK. can you tell us are you writing the mapping functions your self or using a library?

Comment: i'm using knockout's mapping library, but I'm open to options

Comment: If the JSON you're mapping from contains a Children array then you don't need to worry about it.  The mapping library will just right.  Otherwise you need to pass options to the mapping call to create your instances.  See the ko mapping documentation for more details.  I'm assuming that you also allow children of children, children of children of children, and so on, otherwise your object model is wrong.

Comment: The issue is that I want each of the Childen to be an instance of `PersonModel` so that it would get all of the methods it inherits from the `Model` class

Comment: Remember JSON and knockout don't have types and all typescript types vanish when compiled to JS. And ko-mapping only saves/restores observables. To recover the other methods, you'll have to do that manually.  Sorry.

Comment: Also, ko mapping will save inherited observables from Model.